# DialogFlow, how to build a general intent for Yes and No responses

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm building a `DialogFlow` agent for use on the Google Assistant, and it is a conversational model that mainly uses `Yes` and `No` responses to navigate through a hierarchical story. I'm struggling to design the architecture using DialogFlow Intents because there doesn't seem to be a way to create a generic, global intent that uses the system `Yes` and `No` intents. I know you can add these as Followup Intents as a child of a parent intent, but these only trigger once.

I'm using Cloud Functions on `Firebase` as the `webhook`, and will use `JSON` to build the responses and handle the input. Do I need to use entities to capture the responses instead? I don't think there is a system entity for `yes` and `no`.

Comment: Can you not create your own intent with a Yes/No entity type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to create global Yes/No intents:

- Create global Yes intent and No intent. Add training phrases for the two intents.
- Create a yes/no [entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-manage) and then a Yes/No intent using the new yes/no entity
- Make a follow up Yes intent and remove the [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview), which will make it a global intent. Do the same with No

Each of these will get you global Yes/No possibilities.

Since your story is hierarchical, a global Yes/No intent does mean that you'll need to keep track of where you are in the story (most likely with a flag in your code and adding/removing [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview)).